# how to check if sql table date in type string is lower then today's date in string C# winform

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have a table with a date but it is in type string not type date (dd/mm/yyyy).
I want to get from the table all of the rows that the date is lower then today's date,
I have today's date in string and the date in the table in string,
so how do i check who is bigger?

Comment: In english, we use dots to end our sentences and new lines to make text more readable.

Comment: can someone help please?

Comment: Is this mysql or sqlserver?

Comment: i use visual studio 2010 this is qslserver

Comment: @user2164820 my original answer was for mysql. I sure you are using `SQL Server`.

Comment: this is an error message from `SQL Server`: *" 'STR_TO_DATE()' is not recognized built-in function name."*

Answer (score 2):

**FOR SQL SERVER**

You need to cast it to date in order for you to compare the records.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TableName
WHERE   convert(date, [date], 103)  < GETDATE()
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a16a1/3)

---

**FOR MYSQL**

You need to convert those values into `date` datatype using `STR_TO_DATE` in `MySQL`.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TableName
WHERE   STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y') < CURDATE()
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a61fd/1)
- [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: it returns me an error: " 'STR_TO_DATE()' is not recognized built-in function name."

Comment: so this is `SQL Server`. see my updated answer.

Comment: what is (date,[date],103 ) what does it mean?

Comment: `(datatype, columnName, dateFormatCode)`

Comment: great its working...thank you...but it also return me today's date in the table and I used "< CURDATE()"

Comment: i need some clarification, what are you really using? `MySQL` or `SQL Server`? both are different RDBMS.

Comment: I use sql server..at first I was sure im using mysql but i was wrong

Comment: so this will run for you right? `SELECT  *
FROM    TableName
WHERE   convert(date, [date], 103)  < GETDATE()`

Comment: yes it works but it also return me the rows with the current date and i only need the rows that are lower from the current date

Comment: never mind i just added -1: "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE convert(date, [date], 103) < GETDATE()-1"

Comment: you can also use `CAST( GETDATE() as DATE)` see here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5913/4

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as `accepted` by clicking the white check mark (*around 15 mins to an hour later*). This helps keep the focus on older SO questions which still don't have answers. [*How does accepting an answer work?*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)